# how to restore rsa public key from modulus and exponent in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, rsa, public-key-encryption, modulus

Problem: as title

What i got from web server to restore public key:

modulus: 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

exponent: 10001

What i have tried:

First base64encode the modulus and exponent then dump them into xml format, here's the result:

```
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>OWE5MTU4NmIwMmE5MjNkNzkzMDJjNWJlODNmMjU4NjE0NTJiNzhlNTliZDFkMzgzMDQ1YWRk
 YzlkZWJhZDFkYjk2NzU3MjYyNzZhMTBmOTBiZjBkMGFlNDg4MGRiZTRhNTRjODIxZmZmZGIy
 ZjEzOTRmYWY5ZGY1NmQ4NzQwOGJiOTczOThkY2IyMzE5ZmFiN2Y1M2VlNTlmZGI1OGRlZjZm
 NTVjYTkxZGJkOWYyYWY2NWE0YTM2Nzc5ZjUzNTNlYzIxMmQ0YmY5OWJhOTE5NzEwOGFjYjIz
 MzdkMzFkM2VmYWUwMzgwMThkY2IyOTY2NTUxMDY0MWYzMmFjOTllODE1MmYyOTdlMjA1NmVh
 MTRkOWJkNjIzNTA3OTdiMmRhOGVkYzIzNTc0MzI2ZjU3ZTE1NjM5NTIwMDZkYmJiMTMzZTJi
 MTVkMmE0ZGQ2YTU1YWE3ZGViZmIyOGJhNjEwZDdlNjM3MDIyOTU3YjA2M2U2MDU5ODVjNDAy
 YmU0MWRkOGRjM2MzODUyNjQ1MDM0ZjBiMjlmNGZhZDBmNDU0MTlmMDNmMWJiYjcxYzBkYzU0
 YzEwNjlhMDgxZDNlZGI3M2ZkOTNhMjA0ZWRkMGE5OTQ1OWIzOGU2NDg2ZDQxMTcxMzI4YzVm
 NTM5MTM2OTZmOGYyYjE3MTgwMTlkYjliNjU=</Modulus>
 <Exponent>MTAwMDE=</Exponent>
 </RSAKeyValue>
```

Then invoke RSACryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(publickey)

and error occurred:

Run-time error -2146893819(80090005)

Automation error

Bad data

Then i tried to generate xml format public key RSACryptoServiceProvider.ToXmlString(False)

and got

```
 <RSAKeyValue><Modulus>ph0JbRrKHFY5sfmVa9cDPICAtYfT6OKF4KcjgBIKIuFRz3azyCCiE12qP0ZbuHqwb6YQxg6778NJK8S0Xvft6Fu9s0FCO7zUxVRaIw6gumOAV2ih/s+S9pFuxMf3k5w2v5iMA6TFjxS72kCa4O8iIXhOG4u05+o2fRC2cwEYVSk=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>
```

amazingly this key could be recognized by RSACryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString

I didn't see much difference between the former one and the latter one, why does error occur in the first case?

Is there any other way to restore the public key given modulus and exponent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You received a hex (base 16) version of the integer modulus and public exponent. You then converted that base 16 version into base64. However, the XML is supposed to contain the base64 encoding of the integers *as byte arrays* in big-endian format. You can easily do that from the hex by converting every two hex characters into its byte value. The result should look something like

```
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>mpFYawKpI9eTAsW+g/JYYUUreOWb0dODBFrdyd660duWdXJidqEPkL8NCuSIDb5KVMgh//2y8TlPr531bYdAi7lzmNyyMZ+rf1PuWf21je9vVcqR29nyr2Wko2d59TU+whLUv5m6kZcQissjN9MdPvrgOAGNyylmVRBkHzKsmegVLyl+IFbqFNm9YjUHl7LajtwjV0Mm9X4VY5UgBtu7Ez4rFdKk3WpVqn3r+yi6YQ1+Y3AilXsGPmBZhcQCvkHdjcPDhSZFA08LKfT60PRUGfA/G7txwNxUwQaaCB0+23P9k6IE7dCplFmzjmSG1BFxMoxfU5E2lvjysXGAGdubZQ==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>
```

Comment: thanks. after a short talk with web server admin, i've also figured out what i received is hex version, just like your description.